# Xcode renders color several shades darker despite using same RGB

Tags: xcode, colors, xcode5

[image]

The image on the left comes from Xcode, while the image right is from Photoshop. Both colors are inputted using the same RGB value, but as you can see, the colors show up differently when displayed.

Using Apple's own DigitalColor Meter, the Xcode blue color is `RGB(133, 179 185)` while the Photoshop color is `RGB(149, 192, 197)`; and the XCode yellow color is `RGB(227, 205, 102)` and the Photoshop yellow color `RGB(233, 212, 119)`, so there there is no set increment that I can apply to any color.

I was wondering if there is a fix to "brighten up" the colors in XCode so I can get exactly the colors I am looking at when using the RGB coordinates. Thanks!

**Edit:**

I have tried manually entering the RGB coordinates from using the DigitalColor Meter into Xcode, and even then the colors **do not appear as the same** when put in a side-by-side comparison.

**Edit 2**

When I use "Adobe RGB" in the DigitalColor Meter, this is the result. As you can see, the colors still do not match.

[image]

Comment: hi, have you managed to find the culprit? :]

Comment: I didn't. What I started doing after XCode 6 is to just use the 6 letter HTML color codes. These almost always get the exact match. HOpe this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Photoshop tries to use a "color correct" color profile for your monitor. You can change what color profile it uses by going to "View > Proof Setup" and either selecting one of those, or clicking on "Custom" to get a full list of the color profiles on your computer. If you're trying to match Xcode, which is using the default profile, you should look for one like "Monitor RGB" or "Apple RGB". In the "custom" menu, there's also an option to "preserve RGB numbers" which I imagine will help.

This comes primarily from Windows experience, so I'm sorry if it doesn't apply here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I did double check the "Proof Setup" and its presently under "Working CMYK". Another thing I noticed that when inputting these RGB into a third party application like Chrome, or even Apple's own Safari, the colors I get

Answer (score 3):

When you are using the Digital Color Meter, select "Display in Adobe RGB" to give you the proper color code to use when selecting colors in Photoshop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michael. Unfortunately when using Adobe RGB didn't solve the problem. I added an output of the results in Edit 2.

Comment: Got it. I'll play around with it to let you know if I can get a result of the colors to match. Interestingly, if you use the DigitalColor Meter to compare the colors between the small strip of the XCode preview to the actual color it showing up in `Storyboard`, even it is different.

Comment: I'd love to know what you find out because I have the same issues sometimes as well!

Comment: Maybe try this?  Go into your System Preferences, then click "Displays", then click "Color", then choose one of the sRGB profiles (the name may be slightly different based on what you have installed. If you have Adobe installed, it will be called sRGB IEC61966-2.1.).

Comment: Good suggestion - and I did have this profile installed. After toggling into it, the RGB values lifted from Photoshop were still different when putting them into XCode :/

Answer (score 3):

I found out that in the color picker in Xcode is a settings button and there you can pick up a color profile. Default is *Generic RGB*, so I choose *sRGB IEC6...* and it worked fine for me.

[image]

Comment: But I found out too that it depends on on which display you are trying.

Comment: That answer seems to be correct. Switching to sRGB worked like a charm